# Mercurial Named Branches + Multiple Repositories for CI Releases

Tags: version-control, mercurial, jenkins, continuous-integration

Our development group has a group of mercurial repositories for each of our projects that we're working on. Each repository has several named branches: a development branch and the last two stable release branches. In other words, the history tree looks something like:

```
dev --- dev --- dev --- dev --- dev
          \               \
           \               V2 --- V2
            \
             V1 --- V1 --- V1 --- V1
```

We have this setup tied into a Jenkins CI server, so that each time you commit into a repository, a hook tells Jenkins to poll the repository and then launches an associated Jenkins project and notifies the user of the result via XMPP. This part works fine.

We'd like to do our release builds out of Jenkins, as well as add steps of our code review and QA processes to the release pipeline. One idea that I had was to set up a mirror of each repository, as a sort of "promoted" repo. When a changeset committed into one of the development repositories successfully builds and passes code review and QA, it would then be exported to a patch and imported into the promoted version of that repository. Unless I'm mistaken, this would have the benefit of virtually guaranteeing that, when our release manager does a release build, the source tree that he's building from is guaranteed to build and pass quality control.

My question is three-fold: 1) Am I completely misguided in this approach? 2) Is there a better way to do it? 3) Are there any plugins for Hg that would help facilitate the process that don't require the baseline repositories to be redone or the developers to have to change their day-to-day usage (I believe Mercurial queues would require that, but I could be mistaken).

Thank you very much and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems perfectly reasonable to me. You can simplify the promotion process by using:

```
cd Release-Repo
hg pull -r V2 Development-Repo
```

to pull all changes up to revision V2 (for instance) into the promoted repository. Then you can have a project in Jenkins that detects changes to that repo and does the release build.

Answer (score 1):

- If you'll prefer independent repo pull-style may be more usable:

> When a changeset committed into one of the development repositories
>   successfully builds and passes code review and QA

you just pull from "promoted" repo (created as clone of DEV) and don't pull after FAILed tests: in this case tip of promoted repo will be always in good state

- You can use the same repo, but have special "Good" branch, in which you'll merge "Dev" branch after testing - and good state means in this case HEAD of Good
- You can use **single dev branch in single repository** and mark latest passed tests changeset with bookmark

Short dirty sample of test-repo (central repo with 3 changesets and some dev's repos), there r3 (tip at this moment) declared as latest good

```
>hg bookmark -i Good
```

without -r specifier, because it's "a bookmark on the working directory's parent revision" (yes, I have Working Dir for Base repo, maybe it's not needed) and with `-i` (inactive) in order to prevent auto-movement of bookmark on push.

After push to Base from developer's side

```
>hg log
changeset:   4:95c6cb29d14f
tag:         tip
summary:     Small fix of new feature

changeset:   3:3b0236acae9f
bookmark:    Good
summary:     New changes
```

tip is r4, but bookmark "Good" still r3 (and `hg clone URL#Good` will clone repo including r3 only)

After (passing) tests

```
>hg bookmark Good -r 4
moving bookmark 'Good' forward from 3b0236acae9f
```

and log confirms it

```
>hg log
changeset:   4:95c6cb29d14f
bookmark:    Good
tag:         tip
summary:     Small fix of new feature

changeset:   3:3b0236acae9f
summary:     New changes
```

Comment: Good answer. I think we're going to end up using the separate repository though to make the transition more transparent for the developers.